# Creating PHP array for dropdown repeatable fields

Tags: php

I am working on a wordpress meta box that will have repeatable dropdown fields made up of a list of users from the site that is queried from the database.  I am having trouble getting the array to output in the manner that is outlined [on this github](https://gist.github.com/helen/1593065).

Here is my current code:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$users = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT display_name FROM {$wpdb->prefix}users WHERE ID !=1 ORDER BY display_name ASC" );
foreach ( $users as $user ) {
echo '<option value="'.$user.'">'.$user.'</option>';
}
?>
```

The current output looks like so:

```
<option value="User Name">User Name</option>
```

I need the output to look like this:

```
$options = array (
        'Option 1' => 'option1',
        'Option 2' => 'option2',
        'Option 3' => 'option3',
        'Option 4' => 'option4',
    );

    return $options;
```

The way that the dropdown is generated is as follows:

```
<select name="select[]">
<?php foreach ( $options as $label => $value ) : ?>
<option value="<?php echo $value; ?>"<?php selected( $field['select'], $value ); ?>><?php echo $label; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: can you show what your users have after the query, and tell us what do you want to show in the select input?

Comment: see my update - it works for a typical dropdown now, but I cant get it to work with the repeatable fields jquery without changing the markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is wrong then, `get_col` only returns one row.

Instead of `get_col` use `get_results` .